# SQL stmt concatenate(sp*)

Tags: sql, plsql

I’m dong some SQL work this week and I normally write Java.

I need to add some if's into my SQL like so, but don’t want to do any string concatenation.

This should be an easy one: I just don’t know the SQL syntax

I want to make all those "AND" statements "if" conditions for params I’m passing in

Would I have to do something like this:

```
     IF p_sac IS NOT NULL
 THEN
    stmt := stmt || ' AND nsns.sac = ''' || p_sac || '''';
 END IF;

 IF p_value1 IS NOT NULL
 THEN                                                        
    stmt := stmt || ' AND UPPER(value1s.value1) LIKE ''' || UPPER(p_value1) || ''' ';
 END IF;
```

Or is there an alternative to this above?

Basically I've got this:

```
FUNCTION summarize_item_search_data (p_obj_code IN VARCHAR2,  p_value1 IN VARCHAR2,
                                                               p_sac IN NUMBER,    p_job_type_id    IN NUMBER,
                                                               p_value4 IN NUMBER)
  RETURN sys_refcurvalue2
  IS
  result_cur   sys_refcurvalue2;  
BEGIN

     OPEN result_cur FOR

       SELECT DISTINCT jp.id, jp.row_top.mwslin AS mwslin, jp.obj_code, jp.jobload_year, jp.row_top.fiscal_year AS fiscal_year,
                                      nsns.sac, value1s.value1, nsns.nsn,
         DECODE( jp.row_top.nsn_id, NULL, jp.row_top.nomenclature ,nsns.nomenclature) AS nomenclature, jp.row_top.value4 AS value4
        FROM scabs sch, jobs JP, master_nsn nsns, master_value1 value1s, TABLE(value1s.group_id) (+) ntab, 
                 groups pgds
  WHERE jp.row_top.nsn_id = nsns.id(+) AND nsns.value1_id = value1s.id(+)
-- stmt := stmt || ' AND ''' || p_year || ''' = ntab.fiscal_year(+)';
        AND ntab.group_id = pgds.id(+)    
        AND nsns.sac = p_sac
        AND UPPER(value1s.value1) LIKE UPPER(p_value1) 
        AND UPPER(jp.obj_code) = UPPER(p_obj_code)
        AND jp.row_top.value4 <=   p_value4
        AND jp.row_top.job_type_id =p_job_type_id


  RETURN result_cur;
  END summarize_item_search_data;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put it all into your `WHERE` clause as conditions:

```
WHERE
    (p_sac IS NULL OR nsns.sac = p_sac) AND
    ....
```

If performance suffers greatly then you might want to look into using dynamic SQL, but I would start with the approach above.

Comment: so this will add the the statement if the paramater is not null?

Comment: I donyt want to run the query looking for nulls...the Or statment is whats confusing me

Comment: The above code is just saying that if your parameter (`p_sac`) is `NULL` then it isn't considered in filtering the results. It's just basic `OR` logic. If one condition is true, the other doesn't matter.

Comment: Oracle evaluates OR conditions from left to right, so you want to switch the order: (p_sac IS NULL OR nsns.sac = p_sac)

Comment: I don't think that it will really have an impact. Logically the evaluation order doesn't matter (if it did then there would be some serious issues with Oracle) and since the first comparison is between a column within the same row and the parameter then it should be a pretty negligible cost for the operation. The only thing that might make a difference is if Oracle can short-circuit the entire criteria based on the parameter being NULL (i.e., not evaluate for any rows). I don't know if Oracle will do that or not. I'll switch the order though, since you're right, even if the benefit is minimal.